# Define a function in order to locate the zeros of a given polynomial

Tags: python, math, polynomial-math, polynomials

complete the function `FindRealZeros` which accepts a polynomial as a list and returns a list of the roots of the polynomial, in increasing order, appearing as many times as they are repeated

Thus far I have asserted that only polynomials of minimum order 1 can be passed into the function. Any function of order 0 immediately fails the assertion. Next a polynomial of order 1 has its root outputted.

the problem I am having is defining the rest of the function for orders of polynomials greater 2. such as and x^3 term.

```
def FindRealZeros(polynomial):



    assert len(polynomial) > 1.  
# Above i have made sure the polynomial is never just a constant or empty list such as [a], or y = a and [].




    assert EnsureStandardForm(polynomial)
# Above ensures that there are never additional zeros that does not satisfy the previous assertion.     



    if len(polynomial) == 2:     
#######################################################################
#   Here i am saying that if given a linear polynomai, ax + b, then return the root #
#               (given by the equation using the members of the list)               #
#######################################################################
        first_member = polynomial[0]
        second_member = polynomial[1]

        root = [(-first_member)/second_member]
        return root
```

Thus far the code I have implemented works perfectly. the problem is that I am stuck on where to tackle it next. I can try to figure out a way in which 3rd, 4th, etc, polynomial roots can be calculated but that doesn't help me as I need to be able to produce code for any nth order polynomial given.

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like you do not know the basic math behind evaluting roots for polynomials. To give you an overview:

- 1st order: simple, you just give the solution
- 2nd order: simple, there is a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) for that
- 3rd order: still doable, but it's getting tricky (polynomial division required!)
- 4th order and above: not trivial anymore

But you are lucky, there is a `numpy` function [`roots()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html), which exactly fits your needs.

Comment: I do know what you’re saying. I’m a 3rd year math major. The problem is that I need a piece of code that can evaluate a 100th order polynomial. But it strictly has to be done without the use of numpy or sumpy

Comment: Well, then you need to think about, which (numeric) algorithm to use (possibilities to be found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms#Root_finding) and start to implement it.

Comment: @SimonFink : See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3402755/115115 on how a sophisticated polynomial solver can go wrong just from giving the same polynomial in different forms. With degrees of 100 and above one should include good error estimates for the roots.